# PDFxStream cannot display Japanese text properly

Tags: java, pdf, text

I want to read pdf table, right now I'am using PDFxStream to get table data from PDF, but when I encounter Japanese characters it becomes strange characters like this "**ዊᮻᏒⒷⓄ䋳ৼ⋡䋱䋱⇟䋲ภ**" and it has warning because there is an exception.

this is the warning:

> WARNING: Could not parse content stream of object 9,0 due to exception {java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IV buffer too short for given offset/length combination} (3food.pdf)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IV buffer too short for given offset/length combination

this is mycode :

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        //String pdfFilePath = args[0];
        System.setProperty("pdfxs.config.property", "N");
        Document pdf = PDF.open("3food.pdf");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        Page wantedPage = pdf.getPage(3);

        wantedPage.pipe(new OutputTarget(text));
        pdf.close();
        System.out.println(text);
      }
}
```

If you have any clue what happen, I will really appreciate it, Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably a broken PDF? Hard to tell without the PDF in question.

Comment: thank you for answering, I thought so too, but when I try using another library like pdfbox, it can extract all the table but when I sort it out, it cannot beautifully sorting like pdfxstream @mkl

Comment: That some tool can handle the pdf, does not proof the pdf is not broken.

Comment: I checked the pdf using online checker pdf if it's broken or not, it says that is not broken at all @mkl

Comment: this is the pdf that I want to extract [link](https://www.city.otaru.lg.jp/hokenjo/sinki_kyoka_sisetu.data/H27.3-H28.3food.pdf) @mkl

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, cf. [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VECdO.png), at the top the output of your code, at the bottom the original page; I have not found any discrepancies as you described. (Maybe I overlook something, though, in that case please point out more exactly which piece of text is extracted with errors.)

Comment: I extracted page 4 of the pdf, because there is double line in the pdf that I want to sort it out, it's okay with the sample you took tho, there is same problem with the page that I want to extract, the problem I encountered right now is I cannot display the text that you had in the screenshot @mkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug that has been fixed in PDFxStream version `3.7.0`, available here for download or inclusion in your Maven build:

https://www.snowtide.com/downloads

And as a side note, if you have any further issues with or questions about PDFxStream, I would urge you to get in touch with us directly @ https://www.snowtide.com/contact

Comment: thanks for the information, I will try to fixed it and get in touch to you